# How to install both xammp and Bugzilla in same PC

Tags: webserver

Is it possible to install both Bugzilla and xammp in same PC? 
I have installed both in separate PC and both are working fine. Now I want to install in same PC. Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: What problems do you believe you will face? You know how to install bugzilla and xampp (I would use lamp myself though) and installation of both on 1 machine would be to use the same installation path you did on those 2 machines on this 1 machine. Seems to me you know what to do for both pieces of software. Any answer would probably be: install xampp, install bugzilla. Question: bugzilla needs a webserver(?) so what did you install on the machine you installed bugzilla on? So why the need of xamp?

Comment: with xamp I am using webserver for testing my apps. On the same I have I need to install bugzilla for bug tracking. Since both xamp and bugzilla needs apache2 server. Once PC reboots bugzilla will start. Later when I try to run xamp (sudo ./xamp start) then it failed saying one server is already running.